# Dynamically creating a JSON object in C# based on provided values

Tags: c#, json

I am trying to dynamically create a JSON object based on the values provided to me.

1st Scenario - I have all the values

```
 string param1 = "Hey";
 string param2 = "Bye";
 string param3 = "Later";
```

I would derive my Json like so:

```
 private string BuildJson (string param1, string param2, string param3)
 {
       //Passed values for example
      //param1 = "Hey";
      //param2 = "Bye";
      //param3 = "Later";

      object jJson = new 
      {
          VALS= new 
             {
                 val1 = param1,
                 val2 = param2,
                 val3 = param3
             }
      };

      return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jJson );
 }
```

And this works great. However, now I'm trying to find a way to create this same JSON object, without knowing which param will have values. If there is no value, then I don't want my jJson to have that property.

So for example

```
  private string BuildJson (string param1, string param2, string param3)
  {
   //Passed values for example
  //param1 = "Hey";
  //param2 = null;
  //param3 = "Later";

  //Since param2 is NULL, I would NOT want to have it all together in my JSON like below

  object jJson = new 
  {
      VALS= new 
         {
             val1 = param1,
             val3 = param3
         }
  };

  return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jJson );
}
```

Is there an alternative way to dynamically create JSON like this? Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add Properties to anonymous type only if they are not null C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65178867/add-properties-to-anonymous-type-only-if-they-are-not-null-c-sharp)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since this is [Newtonsoft](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json), just include [NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/NullValueHandlingIgnore.htm)

**Given**

```
private static string BuildJson(string param1, string param2, string param3)
{

   object jJson = new
   {
      VALS = new
      {
         val1 = param1,
         val2 = param2,
         val3 = param3
      }
   };

   return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jJson, 
      Formatting.Indented,
      new JsonSerializerSettings()
      {
         NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore
      });
}
```

**Usage**

```
var result = BuildJson("asd", null, "sdf");
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

**Output**

```
{
  "VALS": {
    "val1": "asd",
    "val3": "sdf"
  }
}
```

<sub>***Disclaimer** : I would recommend `Text.Json` for any greenfield development, and would also dissuade you from using anonymous types like this and instead use actual concrete models.*</sub>

Comment: Disclaimer noted. Thank you.