# LINQ with dynamic group by

Tags: c#, .net, linq, group-by, linq-to-sql

I have model:

```
public class Student
{                
    public string Name{ get; set; }  
    public DateTime BirthDate{ get; set; }        
    public string UniversityName{ get; set; }  
    public decimal Balance{ get; set; }        
}
```

I have three `bool` variables:

- IsName
- IsBirthDate
- IsUniversityName

And based on them, I need to create `GroupBy`. If `IsBirthDate=true` then

```
DbContext.Students.GroupBy(x => new { x.BirthDate }).Select(s => new
        {
            s.Key.BirthDate,                
            Balance = s.Sum(x => x.Balance).ToString(),                
        });
```

If `IsBirthdate=true, IsUniversityName=true` then

```
DbContext.Students.GroupBy(x => new { x.BirthDate, x.UniversityName }).Select(s => new
        {
            s.Key.BirthDate,
            s.Key.UniversityName,                
            Balance = s.Sum(x => x.Balance).ToString(),                
        });
```

And other options with bool parameters.

How to generate the query dynamically with `.GroupBy and .Select`?

Comment: You can store them in variables and filter them again in `if` statements.

Comment: You can't easily, because the two `GroupBy` use different key object and the `Select` produce different objects. The two results can't go in the same "type" of variable, nor can the two intermediate results (the `GroupBy`)

Comment: Indeed, there's little common between the two queries except the entity and the aggregated field. You can't even return the results from the same function without removing all type information by casting to `IEnumerable`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe this helps you: Create a class that represents the key for your `GroupBy`:

```
public class StudentGroupingKey
{                
    public string Name { get; set; }  
    public DateTime? BirthDate{ get; set; }        
    public string UniversityName { get; set; }
}
```

If `IsName` is true, the `Name` property of the grouping key will be the value, otherwise it should have always the same value (e.g. null). In your `Select` method, you have to have always every property, but they will be null if the corresponding properties will be false. If it is necessary for you that these properties do not exist, you can't work with anoymous types. Maybe `dynamic` might be an option in that case.

```
DbContext.Students.GroupBy(x => new StudentGroupingKey
{
    Name = IsName ? x.Name : null,
    BirthDate = IsBirthDate ? x.Birthdate : null,
    UniversityName = IsUniversityName ? x.UniversityName : null
}).Select(s => new
{
   s.Key.BirthDate,
   s.Key.Name,
   s.Key.UniversityName,
   Balance = s.Sum(x => x.Balance).ToString()
});
```

Comment: nice approach, thanks. How to do it with anoymous types?

Comment: @Robert Just take out the type name `StudentGroupingKey`

Comment: Additionally, it will be necessary to write `BirthDate = IsBirthDate ? x.Birthdate : (DateTime?) null,`

Comment: @SomeBody  I do not need every property, if the corresponding properties will be false, please suggest what to do?

Comment: @Robert Just ignore those properties if you don't need them. It is not possible to remove properties from anonymous types, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14365858/is-it-possible-to-modify-or-remove-an-anonymous-type-from-an-object-in-c